# Kernel panic error in Parrot Security, how do I fix it I tried everything

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-panic, parrot-os

I can't boot into the new 6.5 kernel.

I am using Parrot Security on my laptop and it recently upgraded from kernel 6.1 to 6.5 but I can't boot into the 6.5 kernel.

When I try update this happens:

```
Building module: Cleaning build area... 'make' -j4 KVER=6.5.0-
13parrot1-amd64 KSRC=/lib/modules/6.5.0-13parrot1-
amd64/build..........(bad exit status: 2) Error! Bad return status
for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (x86_64) Consult
 /var/lib/dkms/realtek-rtl8188eus/5.3.9~git20230101.f8ead57/build/make.log for more 
information. Error! One or more modules failed to install during
 autoinstall. Refer to previous errors for more information. dkms:
 autoinstall for kernel: 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 failed! run-parts: 
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11 
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (--configure): 
installed linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 package post-installation
 script subprocess returned error exit status 1 Setting up python3-
libevdev (0.5-3) ... 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64: linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 
(= 6.5.13-1parrot1); however: Package linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up python3-pyudev
 (0.24.0-1) ... Setting up libwacom-common (2.6.0-1) ... Setting up
 libwacom9:amd64 (2.6.0-1) ... Setting up libinput-bin (1.22.1-1) ...
 Setting up libwacom-bin (2.6.0-1) ... Setting up libinput10:amd64 
(1.22.1-1) ... Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-2) ...
 Processing triggers for udev (252.19-1~deb12u1) ... Processing
 triggers for libc-bin (2.36-9+deb12u3) ... Errors were encountered
 while processing: linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 linux-headers-amd64 
linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 linux-image-amd64 Scanning application launchers 
Removing duplicate launchers or broken launchers Launchers are updated 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

- I tried using `dpkg --configure -a`.
- I tried apt `--fix-broken`

It always says the linux-image-6.5 is not configured

[image: When I try to boot into the 6.5 kernel I get this]

Comment: use the menu at grub boot screen to boot into old kern &fix

Comment: I am booted into the old kernel, --configure and --fix-broken don't work

Comment: keep old kern then?

Comment: I was hoping to get the new kernel working

Comment: I had a kernel panic happen once. Maybe this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/747611/479040) can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyy fixed the problem, here is the step by step process of how to do it yourself as well:

NOTE:

Check the parrot version in the boot first could be 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64

uname -r

1. From the GRUB menu select "Advanced Mode" and start Parrot OS 6.1 kernel;
2. Purge the following packages (which are the causing problem) with this command:

sudo apt purge xtrx-dkms r8168-dkms realtek-rtl8188eus-dkms nvidia-kernel-dkms nvidia-driver dkms

3. Launch these commands then reboot

sudo apt update && sudo parrot-upgrade

4. locate you root partiton
   sudo fdisk -l
5. mount the partition:

sudo mount /dev/sda1

(NOTE: sda1 was in my case yours could be different like sda2 or sda3 adjust it accordingly)

6. sudo  update-initramfs -u -k 6.5.0-3parrot1-amd64
7. sudo apt update && sudo parrot-upgrade

8.sudo update-grub

9. reboot

Do not use the advance options now let it boot normally

10. sudo apt update && sudo parrot-upgrade
    once it boots
11. uname -r
12. sudo apt install xtrx-dkms r8168-dkms realtek-rtl8188eus-dkms nvidia-kernel-dkms nvidia-driver dkms
13. sudo apt update && sudo parrot upgrade

ENJOOOYYY!!!

Comment: Yes, I booted into the older kernel. This error message in particular shows the Linux image 6.5 isn't configured properly. "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64: linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (= 6.5.13-1parrot1); however: Package linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 is not configured yet." I already tried "dpkg --configure -a" and "apt --fix-broken"

Comment: Fixed it check the update